# Find closest value in list in R

Tags: r, list, find

I have a list of labels associated with values. I would like, for a value x, to find the label corresponding to the closest (but inferior) value of the list.

I found a way of doing it, but it looks quite messy and complicated...

```
mylist <- list("A"=0.02,
               "B"=0.13,
               "C"=0.26)

x = 0.14 # B

df <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(mylist)))
df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(df, "labels")
df$V2 <- x > df$V1
maxi <- max(df[df$V2 == TRUE,]$V1)
label <- df[df$V1 == maxi,]$labels
```

Is there another, neat way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We subtract value of `x` with every value of `mylist`, filter out the ones where difference is greater than 0 and select the `names` of the minimum difference.

```
new <- x - unlist(mylist) 
names(which.min(new[new > 0]))
#[1] "B"
```

---

Or a one -liner, where we filter only those values which are less than `x` and select the `max` from it.

```
names(which.max(sapply(mylist, function(i) i[(x - i) > 0])))
#[1] "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend other more compact solutions, but here's a tidy version of what you were trying to accomplish :

```
library(tidyverse)
mylist %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  gather %>%
  filter(value < x) %>%
  summarize(key=key[which.max(value)]) %>%
  pull(key)

# [1] "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list should be a vector:

```
myvector <- c("A"=0.02,
              "B"=0.13,
              "C"=0.26)
#sort
myvector <- sort(myvector, decreasing = TRUE)
#test
test <- x > myvector
#name of element with first TRUE in test
res <- if(any(test)) names(which.max(test)) else NA_character_
#[1] "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to sort the vector then take the previous value:

```
a=sort(c(x=x,unlist(mylist)))
names(a[which(names(a)=="x")-1])
[1] "B"
```

Comment: it's "closest (but inferior)"

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper hope this takes into consideration the inferiority